# Javascript/Ionic3 Overflow:hidden disable scroll in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I have the problem that I cant remove the Scrollbars of Firefox Quantum. Oh Chrome it works like a charm whith this css:

```
 div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  border:none;
  width:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  display: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border:none;
  width:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  display: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border:none;
  width:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  display: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Also I tried  to remove it with jQuery and with adding it directly to the body tag like this `style="overflow: hidden;"`

Nothing of that works. It seems I cant get rid of them. 
How can I remove them?

EDIT:

with adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.scroll-content{}` it removed the scrollbars but I cant scroll anymore on firefox. How can I enable scrolling with overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
<style>
    #container{
        height: 500px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #container-inner{
        width: calc(100% + 17px);
        height: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .content{
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
    .one{
        background-color: red;
    }
    .two{
        background-color: green;
    }
    .three{
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="container-inner">
            <div class="content one">
            </div>
            <div class="content two">
            </div>
            <div class="content three">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd create a fiddle but https://jsfiddle.net/ is down right now.

Comment: width: calc(100% + 17px); worked to hide the scrollbars. Rest wasnt even needed thank you!